# Log4j2 with slf4j incorrect classname

Tags: logging, log4j2, slf4j

I am using Log4j2 with slf4j. I have a custom Wrapper class over slf4j which has a FCQN defined so that it prints classname of the actual class from where the logger is called.

I am trying to run a test case in IDE but the IDE's console are always printing the name of the wrapper class(LogWrapper).

```
18:47:12.987 [main] INFO  com.abc.services.logging.LogWrapper - "Dummy message"
```

What I want is the name of the actual class(Myclass) to be printed in the IDE console

```
18:47:12.987 [main] INFO  com.abc.services.foo.Myclass - "Dummy message"
```

The slf4j logger is created inside the wrapper class and is initialized like this

```
String FQCN = LogWrapper.class.getName();
LocationAwareLogger LOG = (LocationAwareLogger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogWrapper.class);
```

Is there a way to solve this by changing the log4j2 config file ?

Answer (score 0):

No. To obtain the class name of the caller of the Logging API Log4j has to walk the stacktrace (an expensive operation) and locate the method that was called and then find the next stack trace element. It does this by including the fully qualified class name of the class implementing the method that was called. When you wrote your wrapper of SLF4J you don't have any way to pass the name of that class to Log4j, so Log4j is going to think your wrapper is the caller, which is true since it is calling SLF4J.

In order to have a custom logging class you need to create a Logger wrapper for the Log4j API so you can pass the FQCN as a parameter. You can look at Log4j's [Log4jLogger](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.java) and [Log4jLoggerFactory](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLoggerFactory.java) for SLF4J as an example.

Comment: I am actually setting the FCQN in the LogWrapper class. The problem seems to be happening only when I run unit tests. I have edited the description.

Comment: You show setting a local variable named FQCN to a class name. I have no way of knowing what you are doing with that. It isn't at all clear to me how that is supposed to get to Log4j.